# Why does Sherlock think Billy Kincaid is a good man?

Tags: analysis, character, sherlock

In *[The Sign of Three](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2781042/?ref_=tt_ep_pr)* Sherlock said *Billy Kincaid* the best man he ever knew. Following was his quote about Billy

> Billy Kincaid, the Camden Garrotter, best man I ever knew. Vast
>   contributions to charity, never disclosed. Personally managed to save
>   three hospitals from closure and ran the best and safest children's
>   homes in north England. Yes, every now and again there'd be some
>   garrotings, but stacking up the lives saved against the garrotings, on
>   balance I'd say he...

Now I find out that **[Billy Kincaid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Kincaid)** is a villain in comics. Now I know creators of Sherlock do not throw any *dialogue* without any reference.

So is there any connection with comic villain or it's another character from London History or any of original Sherlock Holmes character?

Comment: The answer is right there in the quote. *Vast contributions to charity, never disclosed. Personally managed to save three hospitals from closure and ran the best and safest children's homes in north England.*

Comment: A garotter is someone who strangles people to death, so Sherlock's hero is a charitable man who has killed a few people. A parallel to some aspects of his own character.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no "Billy Kincaid" on the [Baker Street](http://bakerstreet.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?search=billy%20kincaid&fulltext=Search&ns0=1&ns112=1&ns500=1&ns502=1) wiki, nor any Kincaids at all. The [comic villain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Kincaid) you're referring to is from [Spawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spawn_%28comics%29) comics. Not a *likely* connection. And searching all forms of Garrot on Baker Street only returns:

> He is a harmless enough fellow, Parker by name, a garroter by trade, and a remarkable performer upon the Jew's harp.

from The Adventure of the Empty House.

Reading the quote below again:

> Billy Kincaid, the Camden Garrotter[sic], best man I ever knew. Vast contributions to charity, never disclosed. Personally managed to save three hospitals from closure and ran the best and safest children's homes in north England. Yes, every now and again there'd be some garrotings, but stacking up the lives saved against the garrotings, on balance I'd say he...

I'd say this sounds like exactly the kind of thing Sherlock would think and say, not realizing that to [non-highly-functioning-sociopaths](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9sUVrVS4co) it may (and *does*) sound completely **horrible.** It's character-development on-the-fly. Him saying this tells you quite a bit about his personality and his ideas of good / evil in only a couple odd sentences. [Mark Gatiss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Gatiss) and [Steven Moffat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Moffat) are clever show-runners and often say more than appears at first glance.

Answer (score -4):

He's talking about Jimmy Saville. Although Jimmy Saville was a 'childkiller', as in he killed children's minds--by groping/garotting/ raping them--he saved a lot of sick children's lives because of the money he raised for the hospitals and equipment, etc, to treat them.
  To avoid giving the impression that 'Jimmy Saville' was a 'best man' the writers have renamed him 'Bill Kincaid' after the childkiller comic star.

Comment: A point with entirely no evidence at all and not even consistent with the balance of the argument Sherlock makes. Not least because Kincaid *didn't disclose his charitable work* unlike Saville whose charitable work was plausibly done as a cover for his evil child abuse.

Comment: I'm not arguing the point Sherlock makes. I'm deducing that the writers of Sherlock are inferring their reference to 'Bill Kincaid' is actually aimed at 'Jimmy Saville'.

Comment: Do you have any proof (i.e. word from the writers) that this was an intentional allusion to Jimmy Savile? Otherwise, to be honest, this seems like less of a "deduction" and more of "something you just made up".